# Error 10822 when trying to create simple falling edge with signal out

Tags: vhdl

I am having the below error code when attempting to compile.

Error (10822): HDL error at CLEARBLK.vhd(17): couldn't implement registers for assignments on this clock edge

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
    USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
    USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
    
    ENTITY CLEARBLK IS
        PORT
        ( CMB       : IN STD_LOGIC;
          CLR       : OUT STD_LOGIC
        );
    END CLEARBLK;
    
    ARCHITECTURE CLRBLK OF CLEARBLK IS
          BEGIN
            PROCESS(CMB)
            BEGIN
              IF (FALLING_EDGE(CMB)) THEN 
                  CLR <= '1';
              ELSE
                  CLR <= '0';
                    END IF;
              END PROCESS;
    END CLRBLK;
```

Comment: Well that code is trying to create a dual clock edge FF.  If CLR goes off-chip, there is a workaround : instantiate a DDR output FF (OFDDR) : instructions in the synthesis guide. Otherwise, you'll need a different approach to whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: not a vhdl expert, but: aren't you trying to use a clocked register assignment `<=` on a non-registered signal `CLR: OUT STD_LOGIC`?

Comment: CLR does not go off chip. I need to look at the falling edge of the input signal, so that I know when I can clear a counter. I am also not a VHDL expert, so where would I need to make it a signal? I would like it to just "blip" and tell the counter to clear.

Comment: @DonFusili I wish I could get a simulation to run, but that was a battle I had to give up after spending a month back and forth on the Intel forums. I'm using a DUEPROLOGIC board which has a EP4CE6E22C8N chip on it. Glad it worked for you, makes me feel like it's not all my fault! I seem to keep having odd errors with no explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you have not written a register.

In synthesis, your sensitivity list will be ignored, and depending on toolchains, you have written something that will either

- Infers a double-edged flip-flop, which is not present in your device.
- Infers something that would make CLR '1' for 1 delta cycle, so less than 0 time. This can't exist.

Your main issue is that you don't have a time reference, which would determine what the minimum size of your "blip" is. The correct way to handle this is to introduce a clock and make a simple 1 FF delay line:

```
ENTITY CLEARBLK IS
    PORT
    ( CLK       : IN  STD_LOGIC;
      CMB       : IN STD_LOGIC;
      CLR       : OUT STD_LOGIC
    );
END CLEARBLK;

ARCHITECTURE CLRBLK OF CLEARBLK IS
      BEGIN
        PROCESS(CLK)
          VARIABLE CMB_D : STD_LOGIC;
        BEGIN
          IF (RISING_EDGE(CLK)) THEN
              CLR <= '0';
              IF CMB_D = '0' and CMB = '1' THEN 
                CLR <= '1';
              END IF;
              CMB_D := CMB;
          END IF;
        END PROCESS;
END CLRBLK;
```

Comment: As CMB is measured inside the process and changes outside the process it needs to be on the sensitivity list. If this is VHDL2008 use ALL to save typing.

Comment: @JasonM That's incorrect.